# If is possible to set different permissions on certain files when using a remote_directory resource?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm working on a Chef recipe for configuring my Jenkins worker nodes. I have a directory that I need to transfer from the cookbook to the node, so I'm using the **remote_directory** resource:

```
remote_directory '/home/builder/.m2' do
  source 'home/builder/m2'
  owner 'builder'
  group 'builder'
  mode '0700'
  files_owner 'builder'
  files_group 'builder'
  files_mode  '0600'
  action :create
end
```

I also have certain files within that directory that are scripts & therefore must be made executable:

```
file '/home/builder/.m2/cleanup-m2.sh' do
  mode '0700'
  action :create
end

file '/home/builder/.m2/update-m2.sh' do
  mode '0700'
  action :create
end
```

All of this works fine.

Unfortunately though every time I run chef-client on the worker node Chef ends up manipulating the permissions on the scripts twice: it sets 0600 from the **remote_directory** block and then sets 0700 from the **file** blocks. Even though the end result works as expected this continual manipulation of the file permissions is annoying.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically. Depending on how many files there are in that directory, you could copy them one by one with `cookbook_file` instead and set the permissions appropriately. This would be a great example of why `remote_directory` is a hacky solution at best for file distribution, and you should probably look into something better like storing them in a git repo (which supports executable flagging natively) or building a package (again, native support).

Comment: I'll take those options under advisement for future use; in this case they are all more onerous than just living with the constant permission manipulation.

Comment: I would add the `ark` way to distribute a directory as a tarball, which would keep the permissions set in the tarball. This obvisouly need the owner to be managed by chef to get the correct uid at end on target node.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of Chef 12.5.1

See https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3833 and https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2691